# java.util.zip.ZipException with retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm having

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.  
>com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: retrofit2/BuiltInConverters$BufferingResponseBodyConverter.class
```

I can't understand from where this error come and why

Appaered whe i added gson converter from retrofit2

I already clean the project

my gradle

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//compile files('libs/gson-2.7.jar')
// compile files('libs/okhttp-3.4.1.jar')
//compile files('libs/okio-1.11.0.jar')

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Is whole gradle dependencies list provided? The error you have happens when you have library duplicates, eg some other library also has gson or retrofit as a dependency

Comment: First, you probably do not need `play-services:9.2.1`, second, actually delete the jar files from the libs directory

Comment: look in your `libs` directory, and make sure you don't have retrofit there as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//compile files('libs/gson-2.7.jar')
// compile files('libs/okhttp-3.4.1.jar')
//compile files('libs/okio-1.11.0.jar')
```

You commented these, but those are still being compiled

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

You need to actually remove the jar files if you do not want to compile them. In other words, make sure you don't have any retrofit related jar files in the libs folder

Comment: but the duplicate entry is related to retrofit. none of those libraries are

Answer (score -1):

Remove the jar file retrofit2 in libs